# How to set static final parameter from context in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have Class with static final fields and I want to initialize them from my context..Can I do this? Or I have to look for another solution?

Comment: are they are declared final I doubt this will work ;)

Comment: the simplest solution is to remove the `static final` modifiers

Comment: The problem will be that you must initialize (i.e. set) the value of the `final` variable.  You will not be able to do this without "breaking" the "finalness" of the variable using reflection.

Answer (score 3):

Since `final` variables are effectively constants that have to be defined exactly once during initialization, you cannot do this with Spring (or with Java in general). However look at: [Java 5 - "final" is not final anymore](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue096.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's `final`, how'd that work?

You can assign to a *non*-`final` static variable by providing a normal setter using non-reflective Java. You may be able to use reflection as noted by Tomasz to set the final field.

Comment: `final` is a write once variable.  create a class with a `private final String`, don't initialize it, then set the value in the constructor based on a constructor parameter value.

Comment: @DwB That's fine if you can do ctor injection; this isn't always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by "matt b"  you can remove the final from the variable declaration and implement "set once" functionality in the setter.

For example:

```
private static String blammy = null;

public String getBlammy() { return blammy; }

public void setBlammy(String newValue)
{
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(newValue)) // only set to a non blank value.
  {
    if (blammy == null) // set once functionality
    {
      blammy = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```